# Invalid configuration of route 'auth'. One of the following must be provided: component, redirectTo, children or loadChildren

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9, nebular

I'm trying to set up routing to a component in my app directory. For some reason, I keep this error `Invalid configuration of route 'auth'. One of the following must be provided: component, redirectTo, children or loadChildren`. I think `AuthComponent` is showing up as undefined, but I can't get why. I'm not an expert in angular, so I could just be making a syntax error. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Here is my app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { ExtraOptions, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthComponent } from './auth/auth.component'

const routes: Routes = [
 { 
   path: 'auth', 
   component: AuthComponent 
 },
];

const config: ExtraOptions = {
 useHash: false,
};

@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, config)],
 exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

and here is my auth.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NbAuthSocialLink } from '@nebular/auth';
import { NbAuthService } from '@nebular/auth';

export declare class AuthComponent {

   protected service: NbAuthService;
    protected options: {};
    protected cd: ChangeDetectorRef;
    protected router: Router;
    redirectDelay: number;
    showMessages: any;
    strategy: string;
    errors: string[];
    messages: string[];
    user: any;
    submitted: boolean;
    socialLinks: NbAuthSocialLink[];
    rememberMe: boolean;
    constructor(service: NbAuthService, options: {}, cd: ChangeDetectorRef, router: Router);
    login(): void;
    getConfigValue(key: string): any;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular uses annotations to define components, that appears to be what you are missing.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-auth',
  templateUrl: './my-auth.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-auth.component.scss'],
  providers: [myServiceService]
 })
```

The easiest way to create these annotations is to let the angular cli work for you, just run the command `ng g c Auth`, which is short for `ng generate component Auth`, and it will create a class named 'AuthComponent' and register it in your module.

Once that is done you can move your component code into it and use reference it in your routing module.

These components need to be defined in a module for use as well. For simple project you can put them in app-module, but otherwise the general best practice is to lazy load modules and separate components into them, with separate modules being made for components that get shared across your site.

Comment: Hopefully this works for you, lots of power comes from the angular cli

Comment: Thank you, I had tried that before and gotten the following error: `
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts 48:12-25
"export 'AuthComponent' was not found in './auth/auth.component'
ERROR in ./src/app/app-routing.module.ts 44:19-32
"export 'AuthComponent' was not found in './auth/auth.component' ` and so I removed the `@Component` section you mentioned above and got the `Invalid configuration...` error above